# L'Hopital's Rule to determine limit as $x\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling a bit with solving a limit problem using L'Hopital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2x}$$

My work:

$$y = \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2x}$$
$$\ln y = \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2x} = 2x \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{(2x)^{-1}}$$
Taking derivatives of both the numerator and the denominator:
$$f(x) = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$f'(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = (x+1)\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = -\frac{(x+1)}{x^2}$$
$$g(x) = (2x)^{-1}$$
$$g'(x) = (-1)(2x)^{-2}(2) = -\frac{2}{(2x)^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2x^{2}}$$

Implementing the derivatives:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-\frac{(x+1)}{x^2}}{-\frac{1}{2x^2}} = -\frac{(x+1)}{x^2} \cdot \left(-\frac{2x^2}{1}\right) = 2(x+1) = 2x+2$$

However, I'm not sure where to go from here.  If I evaluate the limit, it still comes out to infinity plus 2, and I don't know how much further to take the derivative or apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems that $f'(x)$ is wrong. $f'(x) = (\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}})(-\frac{1}{x^2})=-\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$

Comment: Before you differentiate two functions, it's worth switching variables to $t=1/x$. I'd recommend this for any $x\to\pm\infty$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln x}{(x)^{-1}}$$

$$=2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1/(1+x)-1/x}{-1/x^2}$$

$$=2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x(1+x)}$$

$$=2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{1/x+1}=\frac2{0+1}$$

Comment: What am I missing here? The answer to the question is clearly $e^2$, right? Are you answering some other part of the question?

Comment: @barakmanos, Read the question completely. He actually continued the work of OP and found the value of $\ln(L)$ where $L$ is the limit. The answer is indeed $e^2$.

Comment: There's an elementary limit identity: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$. That trivializes the problem and solves it without using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: But I believe I'm required to solve using L'Hopital's Rule, as the identity isn't discussed in the coursework.  Is this possible?

Comment: @ptikobj You can prove the identity using LHR. See my answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^{2x}$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(\ln(1+1/x)^{2x})$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(2x \ln(1+1/x))$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(2 \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x})$

$= \exp(2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x}) \because e^{2x}$ is continuous.

Using LHR, we get

$= \exp(2 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{(1+1/x)} (-1/x^2)}{-1/x^2})$

$=e^2$

Btw, I think you should know from PreCalculus (in a non-rigorous sense) that

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^{x} = e$

Answer (score 0):

Numerator= $\log\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)=\log(x+1)-\log(x)\to\dfrac1{x+1}-\dfrac1x=-\dfrac1{x(x+1)}$.

Denominator: $\dfrac1{2x}\to-\dfrac1{2x^2}$.

The ratio tends to $2$.